# Freezing columns in wpf datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

I have some tabular data which has a lot of fields in it, and when my WPF application is resized a lot of them are cut off. However, I want to see the first 6 columns always as they are important. How can I achieve this in a grid format? I am using the WPFToolkit DataGrid but can be persuaded to change to a different control if one exists.

Right now, I am using two different DataGrids side by side with the right most datagrid inside a scrollviewer with horizontal scrolling on and the vertical scrolling off. I will also have to either sync the two for sorting purposes or disable sorting altogether.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Okay, it's trivial in that control, all you have to do is set FrozenColumnCount = "6", in my case. Maybe someone else will need this and they can laugh at my stupidity.